# Firebase loop look up data

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
$scope.authorizedUsers = [];
fbRef.child('folders/').child($routeParams.folderID).once('value',
  function(ss) {
    ss.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  fbRef.child('users/').child(childSnapshot.name()).once('value',
    function(user) {
     $scope.authorizedUsers.push(user.val());
     console.log($scope.authorizedUsers);
    });
  });
});
```

I use above code to look up master data then loop them in view using `ng-repeat`

`<div ng-repeat="user in authorizedUsers">{{user}}</div>`

but the looped data display sometimes only. Sometime means I have to refresh several time   to get the data display.

Any idea or there is other better way to look up master data in firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callbacks are invoked asynchronously, so they don't happen within Angular's digest scope. Thus, they are not going to be applied to the page until a new compile occurs.

The solution that [angularFire](http://angularfire.com/) uses internally is to call $timeout(), which will force Angular's compile process to run. Some experimentation would reveal the most efficient way to get this done. Here's a brute force:

```
$scope.authorizedUsers = [];
fbRef.child('folders/').child($routeParams.folderID).once('value',
  function(ss) {
    ss.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  fbRef.child('users/').child(childSnapshot.name()).once('value',
    function(user) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.authorizedUsers.push(user.val());
        console.log($scope.authorizedUsers);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: ahhhh, I always forgot this. Thank you