# Why is this angular value not updating?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularfire

This seems like AngularFire 101, but I can't figure out for the life of me why it's not working.

In my controller:

```
var unamecallback = function(exists) {
        console.log("exists = " + exists);
        if(exists) {
            $scope.data.usernameAvailable = -1;
        } else {
            $scope.data.usernameAvailable = 1;
        }
    };

    $scope.usernameInUse = function()
    {
        var username = $scope.data.color.value + $scope.data.animal.value + $scope.data.digits;
        usergenService.usernameInUse(username, unamecallback);
    };
```

In the service:

```
usernameInUse: function(username, callback) {
            console.log("searching for " + username);
            var usersRef = new Firebase(FBURL + '/users/');
            var user = usersRef.child(username);
            user.once('value', function(ss) {
                var exists = (ss.val() !== null);
                callback(exists);

            });
        }
```

Output from the console, when usernameInUse is fired:

```
//searching for Username2 usergenService.js:23   // username being searched for
//exists = false usergenController.js:47  // does not exist
//searching for Username1 usergenService.js:23  // a different username
//exists = true  // does exists
```

I have the following $watch on $scope.data.usernameAvailable:

```
$scope.$watch('data.usernameAvailable', function() {
        console.log($scope.data.usernameAvailable);
    });
```

But as you can see from the console output - the callback is being hit every time, but the $scope.data.usernameAvailable value is not updating.  That's not exactly correct.  It updates sometimes, but certainly not every time the callback is being hit.  It's also not always 'correct' when it does update.  Sometimes it gets set to false when it should be true and vice versa.

So uh.  Help?

Comment: My guess would be that user.once isn't calling $scope.$digest.

Comment: I had a similar problem and blogged about it here: http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2014/6/2/How-do-I-run-code-when-a-variable-changes-with-AngularJS my solution was to run $scope.$apply().  In your case I would do that in the callback.

Comment: Like @Sargo said, put the `$scope.$digest()` or `$scope.$apply()` at the end of the `unamecallback` function

Comment: @MonkRocker, AngularFire 101 indeed. Typically, prefer $scope.$digest() to $apply(), unless you are going to wrap the code in a function and pass that to $apply()--it does some nice error handling internally if you do. However, in AngularFire, we typically find that it's easiest for the service to do this by simply calling $timeout(callback). This way, your callbacks always trigger $digest and there is no need to worry about $digest in every usage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come Angular doesn't update with scope here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922470/how-come-angular-doesnt-update-with-scope-here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a $scope.$apply() in the callback:

```
var unamecallback = function(exists) {
        console.log("exists = " + exists);
        if(exists) {
            $scope.data.usernameAvailable = -1;
        } else {
            $scope.data.usernameAvailable = 1;
        }
        $scope.$apply();
    };
```

Comment: `$scope.$apply` takes a function--you would wrap the output in that function. As you've written this, `$scope.$digest` is sufficient here to trigger dirty checking and an update (it does not take a function). Switch that out and I'll see it upvoted.

Comment: Please note that `$scope.$apply()` will call `$rootScope.$digest()` so it is not exactly the same as `$scope.$digest()`. I would say `$apply` is safer but less efficient than `$digest()`.

Comment: Had arrived at this solution myself.  Thanks, all.

Comment: @Kato If you have the rep; I suggest you make the edit.  I don't really understand your suggestion.

Comment: @runTarm, I can't see how it would be necessary on $rootScope, when the variable being modified is clearly on the local scope and not available to ancestors?

Comment: @Kato, Yes, it isn't necessary as long as all the things are organized properly. I know the different because once I had surprised on how $apply could works but not if changed to $digest. I can't remember clearly, but it is likely because a directive is written poorly. It mixed the use of $rootScope, $scope, $broadcast somehow in a complicate way.

Comment: @runTam great point about directives without proper scoping. Cheers.