# AngularFire dynamic link component not working

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm building a page which will retrieve data dynamically from a Firebase and utilizes Angular routing to serve a dynamic link.

JS:

```
.controller("IdeaCtrl", ['$scope', '$firebase', '$routeParams', function($scope, $firebase, $routeParams) {

  $scope.idea = {
    ID: $routeParams.id
  };

var ref = new Firebase("https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/ideas/" + $scope.idea.ID);
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  var entries = snapshot.val();

  $scope.ideaTitle = entries.ideaTitle;

  console.log($scope.ideaTitle);

}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});


}])
```

HTML:

```
   ID: {{ idea.ID }} <br>
   Title: {{ ideaTitle }}
```

The {{idea.ID}} works, but the {{ideaTitle}} does not show up. Yet, both console.log's work fine. What seems to be the matter?

Comment: Manube's answer should work. Alternatively, put the assignment in a `$timeout`. And please read https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-beyond-angularfire

Comment: But why aren't you using AngularFire? `$scope.idea = $firebase(ref).$asObject()` and then `Title: {{ idea.ideaTitle }}` should be all that is needed. It is documented here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-objects

Comment: Your title says AngularFire, but nothing here utilizes AngularFire. Also, you haven't read the guide on Firebase + Angular, which [covers these concepts](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-beyond-angularfire) for users who don't want AngularFire. Also, this has been [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922470/how-come-angular-doesnt-update-with-scope-here/21923026#21923026).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would

```
$scope.$apply()
```

after

```
$scope.ideaTitle = entries.ideaTitle
```

work, by any chance?