# Can't get the connection with my firebase database

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm trying to develop a application using Rails, AngularJS and Firebase.

i've created a firebase free account and start to write some code for my angular js controller.

this is the controller:
**chat_room.js:**

```
 var app = angular.module('ChatRoom',["firebase"]);


app.controller('ChatCtrl',['$scope', '$http',"$firebaseArray" ,function($scope,$http,$firebaseArray){

    $scope.isConnected = false;
    $scope.UserData = {};

    var firebaseRoot =  new Firebase("https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/");
    var connectedRef = firebaseRoot.child('.info/connected').on('value', function(connectedSnap){
        if(connectedSnap.val() === true){ 
            $scope.isConnected = true
        }
        else{ 
            $scope.isConnected = false
        }
    });

    var getUserData = function(){
        $http.get('/chat_room/show').success(
            function(item){
                $scope.UserData = item
            }); 
    }

    getUserData();

    /*var msgRef = firebaseRoot.child('chatroom/messagges');*/
    /*$scope.chat = $firebaseArray(msgRef);*/


}])
```

this is my view:

```
<div ng-controller="ChatCtrl">
    <div ng-show="isConnected">
      <div data-alert class="alert-box success radius">Connected to firebase =) <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
</div>
  <h1>hello, {{UserData.first_name}}</h1>
  <p>Send chat from here</p>


</div>
```

if i start the server and load the page the  with the connection message doesn't show and also i recive this message:

in the console : `The connection to wss://s-dal5-nss-20.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=angular-fire-powder was interrupted while the page was loading.`

i don't know what to do this is my first time i use firebase with AngularJS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come Angular doesn't update with scope here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922470/how-come-angular-doesnt-update-with-scope-here)

Comment: You need to use `$timeout` or `$scope.apply` when you perform async updates to your JavaScript variables..

Comment: ok with $scope.apply it works fine but i've still the message: The connection to wss://s-dal5-nss-20.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=angular-fire-powder was interrupted while the page was loading.