# Angular + firebase - resolve issue

Tags: angularjs, firebase, resolve

I have problem with resolve in angular, $routeProvider.
I try to get data from firebase with resolve before view rendering.

```
$routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/login',
            controller: 'loginController',
            resolve: {
                games: function(getUserGames){
                    return getUserGames.getGames();
                }
            }
        })`



angular.module('battleshipApp').factory('getUserGames', function ($q) {
    return {
        getGames: function(){
            var ref = new Firebase('https://blistering-torch-759.firebaseio.com/');
            var defer = $q.defer();
            ref.once('value', function (dataSnapshot) {
                defer.resolve(dataSnapshot);
            }, function (err) {
                defer.reverse(err);
            });

            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
});`
```

But its not working correct. When i put console log into 'ref.once' to check if data is comming, then i can see that data always come. 
But not always view where i use it is rendered. 
Sometimes view is not rendered withoud any error...
What could be the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come Angular doesn't update with scope here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922470/how-come-angular-doesnt-update-with-scope-here)

Comment: What is defer.reverse()?