# Ionic changing background image not working on device

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I have a div with changing background and everything works on web (ionic serve) with no errors, however the image is not appearing on any devices. The variable number is some data coming from firebase, no issues there. I am not sure what the problem is and would appreciate any help! thank you

```
html= <div class="change" id="change" style="background: url(img/original.png) center; background-size: cover;"></div>
```

js

```
    firebaseRef.on('value', function(dataSnapshot){
    var number = dataSnapshot.val().length;
        $scope.length = number;
        $scope.$apply();

   firebaseRef.once('value',
            function (dataSnapshot) { 
   $timeout(function() {

            if (number <= 3){document.getElementById("change").setAttribute("style", "background: url(../img/image1.png) center; background-size: cover;");}
            else if (number <= 6){document.getElementById("change").setAttribute("style", "background: url(../img/image2.png) center; background-size: cover;");}
                }, function (err) {
                    console.error("problem getting data");
                });
            });
```

Comment: When you package up your ionic app into native, the asset URLs change from `http` to `file`. Your code does not seem to use absolute paths. Maybe, some security issues with accessing local files?

Comment: You're not notifying Angular when you receive async data from an external source. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922470/how-come-angular-doesnt-update-with-scope-here/21923026#21923026

Comment: @Kato, thanks for the response, still no luck after adding timeout. Updated code

Comment: What is `number` and where is `dataSnapshot` getting used?

Comment: @Kato,  I updated the code snippet to include that. Number is variable i assigned to some data from firebase

Comment: It doesn't look like Firebase is really involved here. Can you reproduce the same behavior with Firebase removed from the picture? How about by using a setTimeout() in place of the Firebase calls?

Comment: Have you tried replacing ../ with absolute URLs? There's more that can be done here to narrow the scope.

Comment: @Kato, thanks for your time and help! I got it.. The image path needs to be ./img/file.png rather than ../img/file.png